# Need to find the Shortest Time Interval for a given list of ID's in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is the log format where I need to Find the out shortest time interval where all the given list of Ad_id occurs.

Using scala how to find this.

**Log format**

```
 Impression ID, Ad ID, User ID, timestamp

 I1, A1, U1, 10:00am Jan 1
 I2, A3, U1, 10:45am Jan 1
 I3, A2, U1, 10:50am Jan 1
 I4, A1, U1, 11:00am Jan 1
```

**Input:**

```
A1,A2,A3
```

**Output:**

```
Start:       10:45
End:         11:00
Duration:    15 mins
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How do you distinguish between start time and end time? Because according to your example, shortest time should be 10:45 to 10:50?

Comment: I need to find all the "AD ID" passed as an input. In this case the , from 10:45 to 10:50 I only get to "Ad Id" (A2,A3) but my input is (A1,A2,A3), and the shortest interval where I can grab all these elements lies between (10:45 am to 11:00 am)